# Safe use of unsafeCoerce from GADT existential?

Tags: haskell

Say I have

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

import Unsafe.Coerce 

data Any where
    Any :: a -> Any

type Index = Int

newtype Ref a = Ref Index

mkRef :: a -> Index -> (Any, Ref a)
mkRef x idx = (Any x, Ref idx)

(any0, ref0) = mkRef "hello" 0
(any1, ref1) = mkRef 'x' 1
(any2, ref2) = mkRef (666 :: Int) 2

anys :: [Any]
anys = [any0, any1, any2]

derefFrom :: Ref a -> [Any] -> a
(Ref idx) `derefFrom` pool = case pool !! idx of
    Any x -> unsafeCoerce x
```

Provided I only use `derefFrom` with appropriately constructed arguments, will this code work as expected? It appears so, but I don't know what gotchas there may be.

By appropriately constructed arguments, I mean:

```
ref0 `derefFrom` anys
ref1 `derefFrom` anys
ref2 `derefFrom` anys
```

(I will make this safer by encapsulating use of `mkRef` in a monad to ensure `Ref`s are generated properly with a corresponding list.)

Comment: You might also like [Dynamic](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Data-Dynamic.html), which is an already-encapsulated safe use of `unsafeCoerce` akin to what you are doing here.

Comment: @DanielWagner `Dynamic` is really nothing like what's being done here. `Dynamic` uses `Typeable` to verify the correctness of every coercion at runtime. The approach being used here is about using a phantom type variable to have all the necessary type information available at compile time.

Comment: You might be interested in `vault` which implements this sort of heterogeneous container with type-annotated keys: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vault

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes; so long as you can be sure that `unsafeCoerce` will only be called to coerce a value that  is actually of the target type, then it is safe.

Answer (score 6):

I wouldn't do it with a GADT existential. That's not a use of `unsafeCoerce` that the docs explicitly say is valid. I'd go with what they say, and use `Any` from `GHC.Prim` as the intermediate type. `Any` is special in GHC in several ways - one of them is that values of every type are guaranteed to be able to round-trip through it safely with `unsafeCoerce`.

But there's still more to consider.  The monadic wrapper isn't as simple as you think.  Let's say you wrote it the simplest way possible, something like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}

import qualified Data.IntMap.Strict as M

import Control.Applicative

import Control.Monad.State.Strict

import GHC.Prim (Any)
import Unsafe.Coerce


newtype Ref a = Ref Int

newtype Env a = Env (State (M.IntMap Any, Int) a)
    deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad)


runEnv :: Env a -> a
runEnv (Env s) = evalState s (M.empty, 0)


mkRef :: a -> Env (Ref a)
mkRef x = Env $ do
    (m, c) <- get
    let m' = M.insert c (unsafeCoerce x) m
        c' = c + 1
    put (m', c')
    return $ Ref c


readRef :: Ref a -> Env a
readRef (Ref c) = Env $ do
    (m, _) <- get
    return . unsafeCoerce $ m M.! c


writeRef :: Ref a -> a -> Env ()
writeRef (Ref c) x = Env $ do
    (m, c') <- get
    let m' = M.insert c (unsafeCoerce x) m
    put (m', c')


-- a stupid example of an exceedingly imperative fib function
fib :: Int -> Env Int
fib x = do
    res <- mkRef 1
    let loop i = when (i <= x) $ do
            r <- readRef res
            writeRef res $ r * i
            loop (i + 1)
    loop 2
    readRef res


main :: IO ()
main = print $ runEnv (fib 5)
```

This...  Sort of functions, if you use it exactly correctly.  But there are lots of ways to use it incorrectly.  Here's a simple example of it crashing, but a more involved example could have an incorrect type coercion.

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    let x = runEnv $ mkRef "Hello"
        y = runEnv $ readRef x
    print y
```

Fortunately, we don't need to solve this problem from scratch - we can learn from the lessons of history. `ST` could have had similar problems with `STRef` values leaking between contexts. The solution is well-known at this point: make sure that `Ref`s can't escape from `runEnv` by use of a universally-quantified type variable.

That code would look more like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes, GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}

import qualified Data.IntMap.Strict as M

import Control.Applicative

import Control.Monad.State.Strict

import GHC.Prim (Any)
import Unsafe.Coerce


newtype Ref s a = Ref Int

newtype Env s a = Env (State (M.IntMap Any, Int) a)
    deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad)


runEnv :: (forall s. Env s a) -> a
runEnv (Env s) = evalState s (M.empty, 0)


mkRef :: a -> Env s (Ref s a)
mkRef x = Env $ do
    (m, c) <- get
    let m' = M.insert c (unsafeCoerce x) m
        c' = c + 1
    put (m', c')
    return $ Ref c


readRef :: Ref s a -> Env s a
readRef (Ref c) = Env $ do
    (m, _) <- get
    return . unsafeCoerce $ m M.! c


writeRef :: Ref s a -> a -> Env s ()
writeRef (Ref c) x = Env $ do
    (m, c') <- get
    let m' = M.insert c (unsafeCoerce x) m
    put (m', c')


-- a stupid example of an exceedingly imperative fib function
fib :: Int -> Env s Int
fib x = do
    res <- mkRef 1
    let loop i = when (i <= x) $ do
            r <- readRef res
            writeRef res $ r * i
            loop (i + 1)
    loop 2
    readRef res


main :: IO ()
main = print $ runEnv (fib 5)
```

Of course, at this point, all I've done is reimplement `ST` badly.  This approach involves proving your own use of `unsafeCoerce` is correct, won't collect references promptly in the case of long-running computations with short-lived references, and has worse performance than `ST`.  So while it's safe, it's not a great solution to anything.

So, this whole giant answer has been asking if this is an XY problem sort of thing. What are you trying to solve that you think this is a good solution for?